What is the translation of "a discrete GPU" in French?
From intel.com:

Discrete graphics is a GPU that is a separate from the processor. Discrete graphics has its own dedicated memory that is not shared with the CPU.

What is the translation of "a discrete GPU" in French?


Google Translate says: "GPU discret".
linguee.com returns no interesting results.


GPU séparé, mais on ne saura peut-être pas de quoi il est séparé (du CPU). "GPU discret" - je ne pense pas.

@Frank thanks, agreed,  "GPU discret" is not good.

I would say GPU/carte graphique dédié(e)1 or GPU/carte graphique indépendant(e).
The OQLF translates 'discrete component' (i.e. sth like a resistor, a capacitor, or a transistor compared to integrated circuits) to composant distinct and lists composant discret as an alternative from France Terme. I'm not convinced that distinct is a great choice here, nor that carte graphique distincte would be either.
Note that discret is in its mainstream acceptation a false friend. It then corresponds to the English 'discreet'.
A noisy discrete GPU is not discreet ;-)
We wouldn't use GPU discret in French because that would risk to be understood as discreet GPU.
The Latin discretus (separated) evolved through Medieval Latin to mean 'discreet, prudent' and gave the main meaning of the French
discret while the original meaning ('discrete') was only used by scholars and is now still restricted to scientific contexts.
1 Dédié started as an anglicism from 'dedicated'
Dédié, en informatique (OQLF)

Dans le domaine de l’informatique, champ reconnu pour son recours aux emprunts, dédié, comme synonyme de spécialisé, se dit de ce qui est conçu pour un usage spécifique; ce sens est aujourd’hui enregistré dans les dictionnaires et il semble qu’il soit maintenant trop tard pour éviter l’emprunt dans ce domaine.


Seems confirmed by https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/discrete

Pas entièrement vrai pour discret. On dit par exemple tranformée de Fourier discréte, et le mot discret se trouve aussi en mathématiques en opposition à continu.

@Frank C'est vrai mai c'est très probablement un anglicisme. Je ne pense pas que Fourier ait jamais utilisé discrète avec ce sens.

@Frank Ah non, pas un anglicisme mais juste un sens très spécialisé, tu as raison : On distingue en Philosophie la quantité continuë de la quantité discrette. La continuë est celle des lignes, des superficies & des solides, qui est l'objet de la Geometrie. La discrette est celle des nombres, qui est l'objet de l'Arithmetique. Furetière, 1690.

@jlliagre Oui, c'est le terme consacré en mathématiques: 1, 2, 3, 4, ... c'est "discret", les nombres à virgules entre (quand il y en a le bon nombre infini), c'est "continu". Les grumeaux dans la crème sont "discrets", mais la crème entre est "continue", pour ainsi dire.

oui, en math, "discret" est bien le contraire de "continu". D'ailleurs on appelle discrétisation le fait de passer du "continu" au "discret" (par échantillonnage, par exemple)

@XouDo Oui, je connaissais bien ce sens mais je ne pensais pas qu'il existait déjà depuis longtemps en français. Ce sens reste limité à certains domaines alors que discrete est plus généralisé en anglais. C'est pour ça que j'ai modifié ma réponse en mettant in its common acceptation.

En français ce sens (particulier, spécifique individuel) persiste aussi dans l'expression "à discrétion" et dans l'adjectif discrétionnaire.

@XouDo Oui, tous ces mots sont aussi liés à discerner.

@دولةفلسطين Étonnant, France Terme n'a pas voulu de composant désintégré ;-) J'avoue que je n'avais jamais remarqué composants discrets jusque là mais pourquoi pas, en se cantonnant à un jargon technique. En revanche recommander composant distinct me semble discutable.  Tous les composants sont distincts, que ce soit des circuits intégrés, des composants montés en surface ou des composants de base, non ?

@دولة فلسطين L'article d'Intel hlinké par l'OP explique que l'unité dédiée a son propre espace mémoire, alors que l'unité intégrée utilise la même mémoire que le calculateur principal.

Le terme dédié n'est pas très logique à mon avis, et ne m'a jamais plus en tant que développeur. La carte n'a rien de dédié, sauf peut être à son travail graphique? mais c'est le cas aussi des cartes embarquées. Et elle peut d'autre part être enlevée d'une carte mère pour être placée dans un autre, elle n'est donc même pas dédiée ni dévouée à la carte mère, ce qui est à l'inverse le cas des cartes intégrées. Sans savoir de quoi on parle il serait presque plus logique que la carte embarquée soit nommée "dédiée"... Mais je n'ai pas de bonne solution à proposer :-)

@SimonMourier Ce sens de dédié pour réservé/spécialisé est un anglicisme. On est loin de Consacrer au culte divin, ou Mettre sous l'invocation d'un saint. Ac. 1935.  :-) Il a quand même bien évolué depuis. L'OQLF prend acte de ce sens qui est bien établi en informatique.
